# what else we can use instead of import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean as this import is giving me Sonar issue

Tags: java, operating-system

Due to project sec. issues . Not allowed to use com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean . Instead i am trying to use java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean . But in my method i need to know the cpuLoad (getSystemCpuLoad) . how can i get the same using lang.management ? is there any method present in java. lang.* to get the systemcpuLoad ?

Comment: Okay. Let me put my question in this way : How to "getSystemCpuLoad " method in  java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think there is an alternative. At least not in the standard Java SE class libraries<sup>1</sup>.
2. Not all `com.sun.*` packages are considered to be closed APIs.  In this case the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) include this interface.  I take that as an *implicit* statement that this is an open API.
3. If this is just the generic warning from SonarQube that you shouldn't depend on `com.sun.*` and `sun.*` APIs (see [RSPEC-1191](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1191)), my advice is to suppress the warning for this particular case.
4. I don't see how this is a project "security" issue.  Please explain why you think that.

---

> Okay. Let me put my question in this way : How to `getSystemCpuLoad` method in `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`.

One way is just like your current code (presumably) does.  Cast the `MXBean` instance to a `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` and call the method.   (And suppress the SonarQube warning.)

---

The one thing to note is that the `getSystemCpuLoad` method is marked as deprecated in Java 17.  You should now use `getCpuLoad` instead.

---

<sup>1 - If you found and used a 3rd-party library<sup>2</sup> that provides this functionality, or it you implemented your own (in native code, for example), I think you will be making the problem worse.  Now you have an extra dependency to track or extra code to maintain.  Bear in mind that the implementation of this functionality is OS specific, so you would need to find or write an implementation that works on all of your platforms, both now and in the future.

2 - Beware of posts that suggest using the SIGAR library.  It hasn't been updated in a long time, and there are reports that its problematic on some platforms.</sup>